# Index doesn't have all words

Tags: sql-server

I use MS SQL Server 2017 DEV version with a filetable DB and I have big database with about 11.000 PDF files. Some words are not in the index, for example the word "Nachtanzdemo". This word is in one PDF file several times, but when I'm searching for this word, SQL Server shows nothing.

So I put the article from the PDF file with this word in a Word document and put it in my filetable share. SQL Server suddenly finds this Word document. So what's wrong with my SQL Server? PDF files will be found with this dll:

```
C:\Windows\system32\glcndFilter.dll
```

With the following command I´m searching the most common words in my database:

```
IF NOT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mappings') IS NULL
       DROP TABLE #mappings;
GO

CREATE TABLE #mappings (docid INT, [key] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
GO

USE TK_Filetable

DECLARE @table_id int = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.FileTable1');
INSERT INTO #mappings (docid, [key])

EXEC sp_fulltext_keymappings @table_id;

SELECT TOP 10 
    *, kw.display_term, kw.occurrence_count 
FROM 
    sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(db_id(), @table_id) kw
LEFT JOIN 
    #mappings map ON kw.document_id = map.docid
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[FileTable1] FT1 ON map.[key] = FT1.stream_id
ORDER BY 
    kw.occurrence_count DESC;
```

And I get a list of German noisewords, only "der" and "die".

Does anybody have the same problems? What can I do so that my SQL Server will find all words? I had rebuilt the index multiple times.